# sbt docker bashScriptExtraDefines: command not found

Tags: docker, scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I had an issue, which I found solution for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55374412/oci-error-opt-docker-bin-my-job-no-such-file-or-directory-using-sbt-docker).
So, now I have in build.sbt:

```
.settings(dockerEntrypoint := Seq("/opt/docker/bin/service-main"))
.settings(bashScriptExtraDefines ++= serviceJavaOpts)
    
 val serviceJavaOpts = List(
   "-Xmx2G"
 )
```

But it gives error:

> /opt/docker/bin/service-main: line 354: -Xmx2G: command not found.

How do we set bashScriptExtraDefines in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I actually needed to have this:

```
val serviceJavaOpts = List(
   "-Xmx2G"
 )
.map { option => s"""addJava "$option"""" }
```

This works.